# Is it possible to pass a char** as a parameter

Tags: c++

Declaration: `Menu(const char* header_, const char* footer_, const char** options_);`

Definition: `Menu menu(header, footer, (char**){"Option A", "Option B", "Option C", NULL});`

They array gets underlined in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a char** as a parameter

Yes.

The reason your code gets underlined is (probably) because this code is so ugly/unsafe that developers have added special handling in your IDE for such code to be flagged.

If it is legacy code, I am sorry.

If it is your code (or if you simply have access to change it), consider:

- replacing the `const char**` argument with a `const std::vector<std::string>&` (you will have a lot less problems that way).
- replacing the other arguments with const references to std::string instances, or pass by value if this fits your scenario better.
- replacing NULL with nullptr (don't use NULL in new code).
- not using C-style casts in C++ code.
- not using trailing underscores for argument names.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>

Menu menu(header, footer, ::std::array< char const *, 4 >{"foo", "bar", "foobar", nullptr}.data());
```